# User unable to convert lead

Tags: permission-sets

Why is the user not able to convert a lead? we get the following error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about transferring or converting leads? You've highlighted the `Convert Lead` button in your image

Comment: Ho sorry it is about Convert Lead. Where can i find related campaigns.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can have many causes. In order to be able to convert a lead you should have certain permission on some objects.

[User Permissions Needed To convert leads:](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_convert.htm&language=en_US)

> “Create” and “Edit” on leads, accounts, contacts,
>   and opportunities 
> AND
>  “Convert Leads”
>  AND
>  “Read” on any related
>   campaigns

Additionally you should have a role above the lead owner to be able to convert it.

Check it and try again.

Comment: I've checked all permissions. everything is as you mentioned and the lead is in queue. Even i am having same error...

Comment: Got it. Convert Lead is not Checked. Thanks mast0r.

Comment: @NeymarDaSilva You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what the previous comment, a user needs to be able to delete leads to convert leads because they're technically deleting it from the lead table.

Comment: this is not true.  none of my users has delete.  converting a lead does not delete it - it marks boolean isConverted = true